# Making a UIWebView accessible

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, accessibility, voiceover

Simple question.

I have a UIWebView. It displays plain html text with a few headers. I want VoiceOver to read the content of this web view.

It would also be nice if I could make use of VoiceOver's rotor to let the user scroll through content using headers, but I won't get greedy yet.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIWebView` should be accessible with VoiceOver without you doing anything.

Comment: Like I posted in my answer, the problem (for anyone who has the same issue) was that I had marked the UIView containing the UIWebView in question to be accessible. I did this in IB. Once I unchecked that, worked fine.

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered this case, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

What I have learned: If the view that the UIWebView is contained in is marked as accessibility enabled then voiceover will not pass through to the UIWebView.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Our experience was that with this checked VoiceOver would try to read the plain text but buttons would not work.  Turning off the checkbox made VoiceOver work the way we would expect.

Answer (score 1):

read this one :
http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2010/02/iphone-voiceservices-looking-under-the-hood.ars/

Answer (score 1):

From the iOS developer documentation for accessibility.

> A user interface element is accessible if it reports itself as an accessibility element. Although being accessible is not enough to make a user interface element useful to VoiceOver users, it represents the first step in the process of making your application accessible.

You can do something like this (or manually set a label):

```
[_view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
```

There is a lot of information here. I suggest that you consult this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/

Comment: Thanks. I have consulted that and my webView is set to an accessibility element, as is the view it is contained in. VoiceOver still doesn't recognize it though